# No overload matches this call in Cors TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, firebase, express, cors, google-cloud-functions

I want to create API using Express TypeScript, but when I want to use cors it shown error like this:

```
No overload matches this call.
The last overload gave the following error.
Argument of type 'RequestHandler<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PathParams'.
Type 'RequestHandler<any>' is missing the following properties from type '(string | RegExp)[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.
```

I installed the package using `yarn add cors express` and `yarn add @types/cors @types/express`

This is my code:

```
const api = express();
const main = express();

api.use(cors({ origin: true }));

main.use(bodyParser.json());
main.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
main.use("/api/v1", api);

export const webApi = functions.https.onRequest(main);
```

The error is in `app.use(cors({ origin: true });`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Specifying the path is optional for `use`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use), and the [cors docs](https://github.com/expressjs/cors#simple-usage-enable-all-cors-requests) show exactly what you did as a valid example.  IOW, your code is great!  There's no problem there.

There was recently a change to the express type definitions.  It seems like there are two sets:  [@types/express](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/express) and [@types/express-serve-static-core](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/express-serve-static-core).  The former depends on the latter, and [there seems to be some breaking changes](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/40138) in `express-serve-static-core` that `@types/express` hasn't quite caught up with yet.

In that thread, a couple of workarounds are proposed.

You can pin the version of `@types/express` in your `package.json` to version `4.17.0`.  Or you can disable library checking with the [Typescript compiler's](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) `skipLibCheck` flag.

Comment: In my case, I was explicitly defining app.options('*', cors(config)) to enable preflight because I use CORS per route (as documentation shows) I just recast the sentence as the following app.option('*', cors(config) as RequestHandler), where RequestHandler is an interface of express.

Answer (score 8):

What worked for me it was just declaring a variable before:

```
const corstOpts = cors({ origin: true })
api.use(corstOpts);
```

Answer (score 0):

I beleive you are calling it the wrong way. According to the official docs here https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html  you "use" it like thus `api.use(cors())`

And the you pass in the options when you "call" cors like something like this

```
api.get('/products/:id', cors(corsOptions), function (req, res, next) { 
res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for only example.com.'}) 
})
```

So your case it would then be something like

```
api.get('/products/:id', cors({ origin: true}), function (req, res, next) { 
    res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for only example.com.'}) 
    })
```

Comment: You must look at the OP again. He requested for Typescript, and you are using Javascript. It's about @types compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

This solution **works**. Adding a variable before defining `cors` like so:

```
const corsOptions = {
  origin: '*',
  credentials: true
};
```

and then use the variable like so:

```
app.use(cors(corsOptions))
```